# Notepad++ Incrementing the "new" tab

Tags: notepad++

After closing various "new" tabs I used in Notepad++ for storing text I didn't want to save as a new document, I find that my "new" tabs increase in number each time.  Currently, I'm up to "new 3".  It's nit-picky, but this really irritates me.  Is there any way to reset that counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is:

1. Settings -> Preferences -> Backup -> Uncheck "Remember current session for next launch"
2. Relaunch Notepad++
3. Check that box off again (assuming you want to).

This resets the counter to "new 0", which is still slightly annoying, however, I don't know of a way to get it to just "new".